# Changing dataframe column dtypes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am using `df.columns` to fetch the header of the dataframe and storing into a list. A is the list of the header value of dataframe.

```
A=list(df.columns)
```

But each element of the list are in string dtype and my header also have int value below an example of the header:

```
A=['ABC','1345','Acv-1234']
```

But I want that `'1345'` came to list as `int` dtype, not as `string`,
like this

```
A=['ABC',1345,'Acv-1234']
```

Can anyone suggest an approach for this?

Comment: What is the code you tried which did not show the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do it is to iterate through the columns and check if the column name (`string type`) contains only numbers
( `str.isdecimal()` ) than convert it to `int` otherwise keep it as a string

In one line:

```
A = [int(x) if x.isdecimal() else x for x in df.columns ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that '1345' is already a string in your df.columns before assign them to list A. You must search for the source of your df, and how the columns are assigned, in order to assign columns types.

However you can always change df.coluns as you want in any time with:

```
df.columns=['ABC', 1345 ,'Acv-1234']
```